# Trigger to not allow a member to rent if unpaid balance exceeds $50

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I want to create a trigger so that no rental is allowed if a members unpaid balance fine exceeds 50.
At the bottom I have 2 attempts at the problem. But when I insert data for Mike Vick, it does not raise the application error. Mike Vicks unpaid balance fine is 55 dollars so it should trip the flag.

```
INSERT INTO Transaction
    VALUES ('6','Mem101','V104','C1', '14-Nov-14', '16-Nov-14', 'R101');
```

What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

---

```
--Trigger #3

--Attempt #1
 CREATE or Replace Trigger Unpaid_Balance_Rule
 BEFORE INSERT ON Member
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 IF :new.Unpaid_Bal > 50 THEN
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'Balances exceeds 50 dollars, please pay dues before renting');
 END IF;
 END;
/
show errors;


--Attempt #2

Create or Replace Trigger UnpaidBal_50_Rule
 Before insert on Member
 For Each Row

Begin
 Select Mem_num into OverBalance from Member where unpaid_bal > 50;
  IF (:new.Mem_num = OverBalance )
  THEN  raise_application_error ( -20003, 'Balances exceeds 50 dollars, please pay dues before renting');
  END IF;
 end; 
 /
 show error;
```

Comment: Your triggers are on the `Member` table, but you're inserting on the `Transaction` table. So those inserts will never "trigger" your rule checks. e.g. "don't let anyone in through this door" "Oh well, I'll just climb in through the window"

Comment: Your trigger#1 works fine.Do you create table, create trigger and then insert data ? I mean the order posted above is Create table -> Insert Data-> Create trigger which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt 2 will not work since you are trying to query the table Member before inserting the data

Your attempt 1 should work but it is always good to insert number in number column instead of relying on implicit conversion

hence try the below

```
--Insert for Member Table
INSERT INTO Member
VALUES ('Mem101','Mike Vick','Atlanta','320-274-3179',to_date('14-Oct-12','dd-mon-yyyy'),55);
```